# startsWith using error in java

Tags: java

defined variable:

```
 LinkedList list1=new LinkedList();
```

`Object get()` in list1 obtains a node of list1

`Object remove()` in list1 deletes a node of list1

`count()` is length of list1

```
for(int i=1;i<list1.count();i++){
  if(list1.get(i).startsWith('"',0)) //Error here
    list1.remove(i);
}
```

Error: cannot find symbol

> symbol:   method charAt(int)
>   location: class Object

how to fix this problem?
I would like to delete the node in list1 which starts with (").

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but if the return type of get() is an Object then you can't startsWith it as though it's a String, yeah?

Comment: `startsWith` is expected a `String`, you are passing it a `char`.  `"` is a special character and needs to be escaped.  Try `"\""` instead.  On top of it all, `.get(int)` is apparently returning a `Object`.  You would also need to cast the value to a `String` ASSUMING that the value is actually a `String` to start with.  Better to use generics to make sure

Comment: YES! I thought so, but I dont know how

Comment: @user1838839 what is the linked list "suppose" to contain?  Will it only ever contain `String` objects or don't you know?

Comment: If you parameterize the List you can get compile time safety to ensure you'll only put strings in there. If you don't always have strings, you have to check if the object is an instanceof a string, and then cast it. If it's always strings, do something like this...     

List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
char c = list.get(0).charAt(0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `startsWith` is a method in the `String` class; you are using the raw LinkedList type, and thus it is treated like a `LinkedList<Object>`.  If you wish to use Strings, make it a `LinkedList<String>`.
2. `startsWith` accepts only `String` arguments, not `char` arguments.  Use `startsWith("\"")` instead.
3. The second parameter you've supplied to `startsWith` is superfluous; providing no second parameter will assume starting position as 0.
4. You have an extraneous semicolon after your `if` statement.  This will cause the `if` body to be treated as empty.  Definitely remove this semicolon and optionally use curly braces.

---

Your modified solution may look something like this:

```
LinkedList<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();

// [...] Populate the list accordingly here

for(int i=1; i < list1.count(); i++){
    if (list1.get(i).startsWith("\"")) {
        list1.remove(i);
    }
}
```

---

**Additional notes:**

1. Your for loop starts at index 1.  Note that this will not remove over the first element.  I'm sure if this is your desired behavior.
2. As you remove elements in the list, the indices of the latter elements in the list will change.

For example:

```
[ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
   ^
(remove element at index 0)

[ "b", "c", "d" ]
        ^
(remove element at index 1... uh oh, we missed "b"!)

[ "b", "d" ]
              ^
(remove element at index 2... ERROR; index out of bounds)
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, you can do that as well.  But removing at 0 seems more intuitive (to me, at least) and works just as well.  Also performs fewer operations, though I doubt that will make much of a difference.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've realized my mistake.  Forgot that the OP was trying to *conditionally* remove elements.  Ignore my statement about clear and removing at 0 (edited out).  @JohnKugelman's suggestion is best for removing conditionally at the specified index.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a list of strings, you need to tell the compiler so.  Java does not duck-type, you have to tell the compiler explicitly that the Object is a String.

```
List<String> list1=new LinkedList<String>();
```

When it's declared that way, `get(i)` will return a reference of type String and you can use its methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't specify the list type, Java will treat is as a list of `Object`s, and there is no `Object.charAt()` method. Add the `<String>` type:

   ```
   LinkedList<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
   ```

   Or, absent that, add a cast to the `get` call:

   ```
   if (((String) list1.get(i)).startsWith("\"", 0))
   ```
2. The [`String.startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method takes a String argument, not a char.

   ```
   if (list1.get(i).startsWith("\""))
   ```
3. List indices are 0-based.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < list1.count(); i++)
                ^
   ```
4. You shouldn't use `get(int)` with a LinkedList. This method is for [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access). Linked lists can be traversed in order quickly, but random access is slow. You should either iterate over the list sequentially, or use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which does support fast random access.

   ```
   for (String str: list1) {
   }

   // or

   List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```
5. Removing elements from a list while you're iterating over it is tricky. The best way to do it is to use an iterator.

   ```
   Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator();

   while (it.hasNext()) {
       String str = it.next();

       if (str.startsWith("\"")) {
           it.remove();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get startWith on Object , typecast as String.

if(((String)list1.get(i)).startsWith('"',0))

Answer (score 0):

if(list1.get(i).startsWith("\"",0))

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> itemsToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=1;i<list1.count();i++){
    String str = list1.get(i);
    if(str.startsWith("\""))
    itemsToBeRemoved.add(str);
}
list1.removeAll(itemsToBeRemoved);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the object types that your LinkedList will hold or perform a cast when trying to call the `charAt` method. Something like:

```
LinkedList<String> list1=new LinkedList<String>();
```

Or casting to `String`

```
if (((String) list1.get(i)).startsWith("\""))
```

Comment: There is no `String#startsWith(char, int)` method ;)